# Fire Edit event on tablecell programmatically

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I want to fire editing feature for cell in row in a tableview. I am able to edit the cell value when I double click it, but what I want is to fire the edit programmatically when certain event is done.

```
    Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory
            = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
            return new EditingCell(tableCustomer);
        }
    };
```

Comment: table.edit(row, column) is what you are looking for - or else provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, please.